# Regex and yup: Allow a certain special character, but it can't be repeated

Tags: regex, validation, yup

I have this yup validator with a regex that allows all characters bellow:

```
Yup.string()
  .required(MESSAGES.requiredField)
  .min(min, MESSAGES.minCharacters(min))
  .matches(
    /^([a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð '])+$/u,
    'Insert only normal character'
  ),
```

And the only special character that is allowed is " ' ", single quote. But I need to also validate if the user typing repeating times this character, if so, I need to block the form.

In this situation the form allows: Vinicius Sant'anna

But if the user types this: "Vinicius Sant''''''anna", I need to block. How can I improve my regex to also validate this case?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure nobody's name legitimately contains two apostrophes in a row https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: It might have two, but not five or more

Comment: I guess you're in any case rejecting a whole heap of much more common names, including mine (disallowing the letter ř)

Comment: Try `/^\p{L}+(?:[' ]\p{L}+)*$/u`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked, but yup throws the message if I write ' with nothing after, "vinicius sant'anna" is ok, "vinicius sant''anna" it throws the error message(ok), but "vinicius sant'" it also throws the message

Comment: If there can be leading and trailing quotes try `/^'?\p{L}+(?:[' ]\p{L}+)*'?$/u`, `'?` is an optiona  quote

Comment: @sabik do you have a suggestion on how can I improve this validation so the form accepts all kinds of names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^'?\p{L}+(?:[' ]\p{L}+)*'?$/u
```

*Detais*:

- `^` - start of string
- `'?` - an optional leading `'`
- `\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `(?:[' ]\p{L}+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a `'` or space and then one or more letters
- `'?` - an optional `'` char
- `$` - end of string
- `u` - enables Unicode property classes in the regex.

If you need to also support diacrtics use

```js
/^'?(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+(?:['\s](?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+)*'?$/u
```

where `(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+` matches one or more occurrences of a letter and then zero or more diacritics. `\s` matches a whitespace.

Comment: It is throwing the error if I put space, but the form needs to accept space character, can I modify this regex to accept it?

Comment: @ViníciusCardoso `\s` supports whitespace. If you use the regex correctly, it will work.

Comment: I tried to use, but even so its throwing the error. I tried \s in both your examples, but it didn't work :c

Comment: In this case, it is throwing the error if I write space character with nothing after it, if I write "vinicius " it throws error, but if I write something after the space character the error goes away, for example "vinicius cardoso". But I can't throw the error in the first example, the form needs to accept the space character.

Comment: @ViníciusCardoso Then make the pattern match zero letters at the end, `/^'?\p{L}+(?:[' ]\p{L}*)*'?$/u`

Comment: Now its allowing space but also allowing the " ' "

Comment: @ViníciusCardoso Please add more test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kasc3d/1) and share an updated link.

Comment: updated link: https://regex101.com/r/Kasc3d/3

The first example is what I need to let it pass, a word with space character without getting an error, the second example is ok, the third example the form needs to throw an error.

Comment: @ViníciusCardoso Ok, try `^'?\p{L}+(?:[' ]\p{L}+)*[' ]?$` / `^'?\p{L}+(?:['\s]\p{L}+)*['\s]?$`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kasc3d/4).

Comment: It worked, I liked that site, I'll try to use it more often. Thank you so much again, the world is a better place with people like you in it!